# FreeBSD 8.0 upgraded from 7.2 won't configure network interface from rc.conf

Tags: networking, configuration, freebsd

Prior to upgrade, the network interfaces were configured with brex_ifconfig statements in rc.conf. After upgrade, this fails.

If I log in locally, and do ifconfig from the command line, and then start by hand all the services that failed because they couldn't find a configured network interface, everything works fine.

I've tried destroying the interfaces to re-configure them, but ifconfig destroy fails with an error message.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: I suggest that, after logging in locally, you restart networking (something like /etc/rc.d/netif restart) and look for errors, then paste those here. Sorry I can't be more specific, as I don't have FreeBSD installed at the moment.

Comment: What does `brex_ifconfig` mean ?

Comment: The interfaces are bre0 and bre1, so statements beginning bre0_ifconfig and bre1_config are used in rc.conf. Thanks for the hint, @fission. I found that /etc/network.subr was incomplete.

Comment: @bocarp: Ah. It should be `ifconfig_bre0` anyway..

Comment: Oh, duh. Yes, I was doing it from memory. You get the idea, anyway. And it all works lovely, now.

Comment: when in doubt check `/etc/defaults/rc.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /etc/network.subr is complete